# VS2008 Project runs in Asp.Net Developement Server although it's added to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-development-serv

I have two projects(GUI and WebService). Both are added in IIS but when I run the GUI project it starts in ASP.NET Developement Server instead of IIS. I know that in properties of the project we have to change to use IIS Web Server and in WebService i have it done but in Gui there's no "Properties" - instead of this there is "Property Pages" and there's no option to set project's default server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you on the right way, Property Pages -> Start Options
in the Server section select "Use custom server" 
and specify in the "Bse URL:" texbox your IIS url